# Android UDP send around 500 packages per second

Tags: android, sockets, udp

on a current project I caputre data from a wristband over Bluetooth.
I need to send this data, as soon as they arrive on the phone, to my pc.
The wristband sends with 64 Hz. So 64 values per second.

For me its important, that all packages arrive at the phone.
On the pc I open a hotspot to which the smartphone connects.
I send all the packages over one socket.
To prevent data loss caused by UDP. I send every package 5 times.
But when I test the code not all packages arrive at the pc.

I think its not a problem of coding as most packages arrive at the pc.
Could it be that 320 packages at a size of 50 Bytes is too much to send?

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using TCP then?

Comment: Its neccessary that when the smartphone is in the "Wifi-Area" too connect as soon as possible to it and start sending. With TCP it takes a much longer time up to the first package sent. So we want to prevent this.

Comment: So instead of sending each packet 5 times, perhaps you should cache the packets and wait for an ACK on each one before throwing it away. If no ACK comes back, re-transmit the packet after X seconds. Your bandwidth will probably be smaller and assuming RAM is not a terrible issue, you will almost be guaranteed that you won't lose anything.

Comment: So basically this is a form of "tcp-lite". I will give it a try.  Thanks